# How to get rid of interface used to fix circular type reference

Tags: typescript

I am trying to get rid of an interface used as Array by inferring its element type.

The `type test` is `(string | string[])[]`, but it should be `string[][]`.

How can I fix this?

```
type test = MyType<{ type: 'array'; items: { type: 'array'; items: { type: 'string' } } }>

type MyType<T> = T extends { type: 'string' }
  ? string
  : T extends { type: 'array' }
  ? UnpackMyArray<T extends { items: infer Items } ? MyArray<Items> : never>
  : never

interface MyArray<Declaration> extends Array<MyType<Declaration>> {}
type UnpackMyArray<T> = T extends Array<infer Item> ? Item[] : never
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I knew what was going on in there, but I can't figure it out. Circumventing the circular type detectors by wrapping an otherwise forbidden self-referencing conditional type in an interface and then immediately unwrapping it is a trick and might be brittle.  I've seen warnings against [other such tricks](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897#issuecomment-401418254); not sure how this one will ultimately fare but I'd be wary of relying on it.  (Note, it wouldn't be an issue if you just returned your `MyArray` type instead... it's the additional unwrapping that is dubious here).

Anyway, I tried to analyze it but even slight changes I made to the code ended up confusing the compiler enough to output types like `any` for the whole thing.  In the end, I re-created your logic and removed as much [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) as possible, replacing it with [property lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types).  Type inference is a bit more "magical" than property lookups, and I am less confident about what the outcome will be with inference than I am with lookups.  Specifically, I made the following kind of changes:

- Instead of `T extends {prop: infer P} ? P :` I would use `T extends {prop: unknown} ? T['prop'] :`
- Instead of `T extends Array<infer L> ? L :` I would use `T extends Array<any> ? T[number] :`.

Also I collapsed nested conditional types where possible (but I see you edited your question to do this also) as in

- Instead of `T extends {prop: infer P} ? P extends Q ? ... : never` I collapsed to `T extends {prop: Q} ? ...`.

---

Now let's see what you get:

```
type DeclarationType<D> = D extends { type: 'string' } ? string :
  (D extends { type: 'array', items: unknown } ? MyArray<D['items']> : never)[number][];

interface MyArray<D> extends Array<DeclarationType<D>> { }

type test = DeclarationType<{ 
  type: 'array'; items: { type: 'array'; items: { type: 'string' } } 
}>
```

That gives me `type test = string[][]`, as you expect.

[Playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhDGAbAhgJ2cAlgewHYBVwIAeGAPigF5YoIAPYCXAEwGcoBvKUSALigBErYKky4A5gKgBfAFBQoAfijDRE+VH4AKGLQZM2nbkX4C06EAIDcUTIwC2rfgFdcAa1zYA7rhkaFCsoAsiAAgqgWpADaAnYQjgIAumT+Afy4EABuEKgAlFG4zvYARjmJUYlWsrJijKgAZsjw0CHhkeR6jCzsbcggpAgo6Fh4hJCkZBQccrI80IzCVLCDaBg4BETEHBpzpuZ91hpxjvxcu4L7ljbHTkbnQiJikjIyVdJkVUA)

---

Is it perfect?  Probably not.  Can you expect it to keep working in new versions of TypeScript?  Who knows.  Did I technically answer your question with a version that works as of April 26, 2019 on TS 3.3.3 and whatever version of TS is on my laptop now (TS 3.5.0-dev.20190424 as it happens)?  Uh, yes!

Hope that helps; Good luck.

Comment: Much appreciated! I'm too focused on `infer` as often TS blow up in my face and I use `infer` as a rescue. You make good adjustments - it helps!